# VBA automation error when attempting to send out to a specified list of emails

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

SO i am trying to send out a email with different addresses from excel's vba and keep getting an automation error when running through the code. The code will send the first email but not run after it. My code is attached below and a picture of the spreadsheet[text](https://stackoverflow.com)

[storing data from worksheet in array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsb3Y.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVtYq.png

[outputting array to outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nljaq.png)

[spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjuPJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsb3Y.png)

I tried the on error resume on next solution but this did not work and continued to work the same way and am not sure how else to fix it

Comment: I'd suggest pasting the problematic code instead of screenshots.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following VBA code to send bulk emails with attachments. Have been using this for couple years without issue. Need to set your default account in outlook. For attachment you can use file path as value
[Sample excel column order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nwwN.png)

```
Sub BulkMail()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Activate
'Creating references to Application and MailItem Objects of Outlook
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem

'Creating variable to hold values of different items of mail
Dim sendTo, subj, atchmnt, msg, ccTo, bccTo As String

Dim lstRow As Long

'you can have any sheet name below.
 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Getting last row of containing email id in column 3.
lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

'Variable to hold all email ids

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C2:C" & lstRow)

'initializing outlook object to access its features
Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
On Error GoTo cleanup 'to handle any error during creation of object.

'Loop to iterate through each row, hold data in of email in variables and send 'mail to each email id.

For Each cell In rng
    sendTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2
    subj = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value2
    msg = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value2
    atchmnt = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value2
    ccTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value2
    bccTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value2

    On Error Resume Next 'to hand any error during creation of below object
    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'Writing and sending mail in new mail
    With outMail
        .To = sendTo
        .cc = ccTo
        .BCC = bccTo
        .Body = msg
        .Subject = subj
        .Attachments.Add atchmnt
        .Send 'this send mail without any notification. If you want see mail
              'before send, use .Display method.
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0 'To clean any error captured earlier
    Set outMail = Nothing 'nullifying outmail object for next mail
 Next cell 'loop ends

cleanup: 'freeing all objects ceated
        Set outApp = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the `Send` method in the loop for the same item. You need to create a new item instance by calling the `CreateItem` in the for loop where the `Send` method is called. Just keep the rule - `CreateItem` -> `Send` for each iteration.